# RoR: Accept File Upload and Copy&Paste Upload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to give the user the possibility to upload a CSV file with the HTML input OR to copy & paste the column data into a text box and then creating a CSV File, to save it to the model.

Do you know any good libraries or a pragmatic approach how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

### Pseudo-implementation Example:

*Tested Working on Rails 5.2 with `ActiveStorage`*

Assuming you already [set up `ActiveStorage`](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#setup),

**app/models/foo.rb**

```
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :csv

  # sets `csv` attachment from a String input
  # i.e. value = "Name,Age,\nBen,24,\nJenny,23,\nGeorge,21,\n"
  def csv_string=(value)
    tempfile = Tempfile.new
    tempfile << value
    tempfile.close

    self.csv = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(
      tempfile: tempfile,
      type: 'text/csv',
      filename: 'some_file_name.csv' # << change this filename accordingly
    )
  end
end
```

**app/views/foos/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: @foo, local: true) do |form| %>
  <!-- ... -->
  <%= form.file_field :csv %>
  <%= form.text_area :csv_string %>
  <!-- ... -->
<% end %>
```

**app/controllers/foos_controller.rb**

```
class FoosController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @foo = Foo.new(foo_params)
    # ...
  end

  private

  def foo_params
    params.require(:foo).permit(:csv, :csv_string)
  end
end
```

#### Your `TODO`:

- add some JS that will allow the user to select ONLY EITHER "file upload" or "text area" for the CSV (i.e. some JS that will hide/show (and "enable"/"disable") one of the inputs accordingly), because if you don't have this interaction, it will be confusing to the user because both file_field and text_area above appear side-by-side on the form. (but that only one would work: `csv_string` will override the value of `csv` if both are inputted by the user)